# python ThreadPoolExecutor closes connection before task is completed

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, threadpoolexecutor, binance

I'm trying to retrieve cryptocurrency historical data from Binance API and store it to my postgreSQL database.
This is how my script looks like:

```
import config
from binance.client import Client
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from tqdm import tqdm
import concurrent.futures

client = Client(config.BINANCE_API_KEY, config.BINANCE_API_SECRET)
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host=config.DB_HOST, database=config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASSWORD)
cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)


cursor.execute(
    "SELECT concat(symbol, quote_asset) as ticker FROM currency")
tickers = cursor.fetchall()

coin_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    coin_data.append(ticker)


def unixtimetodatetime(unixtime):
    return unixtime.format("'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'")


def retrieve_klines(ticker_symbol):
    minute_prices = []
    for ticker in tqdm(coin_data):
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(
            f"{coin_data.get(ticker)}", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, "4 May 2018", "21 May, 2021")
        for coin in klines:
            coin[0] = unixtimetodatetime(coin[0])
            coin[6] = ticker[1]
            minute_prices.append(coin[0:7])
        for row in minute_prices:
            
            sql_insert = f"""INSERT INTO currency_price (dt, open, high, low, close, volume, currency_id) VALUES ({row[0]}, {row[1]}, {row[2]}, {row[3]}, {row[4]}, {row[5]}, (SELECT id FROM currency WHERE symbol = '{row[6]}')) ON CONFLICT (dt, currency_id) DO NOTHING"""
            cursor.execute(sql_insert)

            connection.commit()


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(retrieve_klines, coin_data)
```

Now the problem is that when using a ThreadPoolExecutor, the script finishes immediately after all the threads are started without actually retrieving any data.
I've read the concurrent.futures documentation and it states that, if I use context manager with the executor, I don't need to indicate 'wait' parameter.
What could be a solution to keep the the program running until the data is retrieved and stored to my DB?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Doing a mockup that just maps some dummy tasks (``print`` and/or ``sleep``) does not replicate the issue (i.e., the script waits for completion).

Comment: Well, in this case it needs to connect to Binance API with API keys and I really wouldn't show mine. As I'm using tqdm library, I can only tell that once the script is ran, progress bars for every single currency appear at 0% and once all of the progress bars are shown, the program completes.

Comment: So the problem does not appear when not using the Binance API?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the flow without the API, but I'm having issues (I'm still very inexperienced), so I cannot tell that yet. Anyway, will get back as soon as I checked it.

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate the flow as I need to move on. Instead of inserting the data from API straight to my DB, I retrieved it to CSV files and will be inserting it to DB now. @MisterMiyagi, thanks for taking a look into this and sorry for the time wasted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure though that the issue is with the postgresql as insert statement would block the whole flow or insert partial data based on where I would put it inside the function.